# .Net Core app not starting, showing error that not installed but it is installed

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core

I'm trying to run my app on a different computer, i have installed the net core runtimes but the app isn't starting.
It shows an error that you must install .Net Core (see in picture)

[Error image and installed dotnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Euo0s.png)

Comment: Can you show your applications properties? Might be in a different .net core version.

Comment: Have you installed the HostingBundle? I always have to install that before beig able to host on IIS.

Comment: The application is on 3.1, and the sdk on the compiling computer is 3.1.201

Comment: Isn't the HostingBundle for asp.net? The app is C#